# Single word for "refusing to move to next activity unless present one is completed."

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A **perfectionist** is defined as follows:

> a person who refuses to accept any standard short of perfection.

But I am looking for a noun which describes a person who refuses to move forward in
an activity or thought unless the present one is sorted out. Kind of like having a mental block to move ahead, but by choice.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's not listed in the major dictionaries, but Wiktionary mentions [completionist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/completionist):

> One who insists on completion.

I wouldn't count on your audience knowing exactly what it means, so you might have to explain it first, but you probably wouldn't get any closer with a single word.

Comment: Insisting on completion doesn't necessarily mean insisting on completion of one task before moving on to another, only that the task must be completed.  IMO anyway.  I've heard the term in the context of gaming, and one would never think a completionist would have to finish one game before starting the next.

Comment: I've only heard *completionist* in the context of a collector who wants to own "one of everything".

Comment: @nasch: By semantical definition, I agree with your distinction. But considering its practical usage in reference to gamers, the distinction does not exist. "Completionist" is even used (loosely and not pedanctically correctly) for people who keep playing a game longer than the speaker would.

Comment: @Flater, eep - I commented on the wrong answer. I’ve moved it to BB On’s answer where it makes much more sense! Thanks.

Comment: @Flater What do you mean by the distinction does not exist?  If you mean there isn't a word for someone who completely finishes one game before starting the next, I agree.

Comment: Note that the word _completist_ is sometimes used as a synonym, though it is apparently less common.

Comment: *completist* is the only form I've heard in the collector sense.

Answer (score 25):

I would use *single-minded* ([Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/single-minded))

> : having one driving purpose or resolve : DETERMINED, DEDICATED

or *unitasker* ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unitasker))

> A person who does a single thing at a time.

Comment: See also "methodical" or "single minded".

Comment: Or “one track mind.”

Comment: Unitasker is great. I use monotasking in a similar way, and have anecdotally heard it more than unitasking.

Comment: This does not say *why* your answer is right. It has no explanation. It has no original content. Please edit this answer to amend these deficiencies.

Comment: How does one "explain" how this is correct? That the word matches the definition is self-evident.

Answer (score 10):

**Serialist** could have something of the meaning you want.  The problem is that it has some specific meanings in other contexts, and doesn't seem to have been used in relation to the completion of tasks.  The closest meaning in the OED is meaning #4, but it relates more to learning rather than the completion of tasks.

> 1. A person who writes stories, novels, etc., for publication in serial form.
> 2. *Philosophy.* A believer in or advocate of a theory based on the analysis of the self as a series or succession of states or events. *rare.*
> 3. *Music.* A composer, advocate, or admirer of serial music or composition.
> 4. *Psychology.* A person who tends to acquire knowledge about something by consideration of a series or sequence of items, facts, etc., in turn.

Examples given for meaning 4 are:

> "Serialists learn, remember and recapitulate a body of information in small, well-defined and sequentially-ordered segments."
>
> "Operation learning is the style of those who are routine serialists; comprehension learning that of routine holists."

More broadly, you could say that such a person is "stubbornly serial" or "doggedly serial" in completing their tasks, though you'd probably have to add a subordinate clause explaining what you mean.

Answer (score 9):

**Single-threaded** (a term borrowed from computer science)

> In computer programming, single-threading is the processing of one
>   command at a time. The opposite of single-threading is multithreading.
>   Thread (computing) - Wikipedia
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)

"He had a single-threaded mind"

Comment: I have never heard of someone having a "single-threaded mind", but I have heard of them having a "one-track mind"...

Comment: "Multi-tasker" is in common use for a person who can chop and change between activities on a frequent basis without his/her productivity suffering. I think calling somebody a "single-tasker" would be understood, though I've not heard it in use. (It might cause hurt or offence). These terms are also borrowed from computer science.

Answer (score 8):

You could use **Linear**, according to [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linear):

> of, relating to, or based or depending on sequential development

Comment: I'm not sure that if you described someone as "linear", I would assume that you meant they would refuse to move to the next activity until their current one was completed.

Comment: What would you assume about their work habits?

Comment: The term "sequential" (used in the above definition of linear) is another good choice to describe a linear method of working.

Comment: This does not say *why* your answer is right. It has no explanation. It has no original content. Please edit this answer to amend these deficiencies.

Answer (score 7):

*Sticktoitiveness* ([Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/words/sticktoitiveness/)):

> Sticktoitiveness — meaning dogged perseverance — regularly appears in
>   three forms: the unhyphenated form, stick-to-it-iveness, and
>   stick-to-itiveness. The three-hyphened form was most common when the
>   word came about in the U.S. in the late 19th century (as attested by
>   the OED‘s examples and in historical news searches). But today, the
>   two-hyphened stick-to-itiveness is most common, and the unhyphenated
>   form is still comparatively rare. The last form is steadily gaining
>   ground, though, and is likely to prevail in the near future, if the
>   word stays in the language.

Comment: Thanks for the fine example of the evolution of solidification in hyphenated words. I'm not sure how often I'll use the word in actual speech, though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I've heard the word used a number of times in actual speech (not so much since I retired, though).  Not sure I've ever seen it in print prior to looking it up, though.

Comment: It's probably too big a risk when you've misplaced your article giving the correct hyphenation/s. (I really struggled to find where to paste the article in a document I knew I had on 'the trend towards solidification over time of compound nouns, the rate generally being faster in the States'. I suppose I had to stick to it before I could paste it.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If am not wrong it's an adjective, right ?

Comment: @Rahul, I’d say noun because it ends "-ness" like sadness and prettiness (those are both nouns in thefreedictionary.com). For example, sometimes I suffer from a certain sadness/prettiness...

Comment: This does not say *why* your answer is right. It has no explanation. It has no original content. Please edit this answer to amend these deficiencies.

Answer (score 6):

If the behavior is particularly extreme or obsessive, you might call them **monomaniacal**. According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monomania):

> **monomania**: excessive concentration on a single object or idea

Comment: I do not know who nominated this for deletion, but looks OK to me.

Answer (score 5):

You could say that someone is "mired" in a task - a mire is like a swamp or bog, so it's a metaphor for being stuck in something.   This doesn't necessarily mean that they wouldn't like to leave it and do something else, but it may often be the case that they are refusing to move on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually looking for a noun. What you suggested is a verb. I might use it too.

Comment: Is this a good usage ? **Sometimes I get mired in my thoughts.**

Comment: Yes, that works I think.

Answer (score 4):

First word that came to mind is *persistent* (from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/persistent), 2019):

> Obstinately refusing to give up or let go.

This means that when someone is engaging in a task there is a reluctance to let go of performing the task, even when not appropriate anymore.

From [Cohen & Levesque](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.8441&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (1990):

> It does not seem unreasonable to require that a robot not procrastinate forever. Moreover, we surely would want a robot to be **persistent** in pursuing its goals, but not fanatically so. Furthermore, we would want a robot to drop goals given to it by other agents when it determines the goals need not be achieved.

Comment: Persistent does not imply _to the exclusion of other tasks_

Comment: This does not say *why* your answer is right. It has no explanation. It has no original content. Please edit this answer to amend these deficiencies.

Answer (score 3):

Some personality tests use the term **completer-finisher** alternatively just **completer** or **finisher**. An example personality test is Myers Briggs, although some other personality tests use these terms too. A completer-finisher goes the extra mile to make sure that everything is just right and can frustrate their team mates at work by wanting to get everything done exactly right before moving on to the next task.

Answer (score 3):

*fixated*

[Google dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20fixated&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS813US813&oq=define%20fixated&aqs=chrome..69i64.3027j0j7) (for fixate):

> cause (someone) to acquire an obsessive attachment to someone or something.

Comment: This does not say *why* your answer is right. It has no explanation. It has no original content. Please edit this answer to amend these deficiencies.

Answer (score 2):

When I read the title of your question 'Single word for “refusing to move to next activity unless present one is completed.”' I imdieately thought of 'go/no go'

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go/no_go)

> In general go/no go testing refers to a pass/fail test (or check) principle using two boundary conditions or a binary classification. The test is passed only when the Go condition is met and also the No go condition fails.

**But** it does not meet several of your criteria, it is not a noun, it does not describe a person, and it is not a single word.

In my experience (US Army) it is often used like a single word to describe where the only options are move forward or not.

While it might not be exactly what you are looking for, it may provide alternate usage in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, you may be able to use **[prerequisite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prerequisite)** as a reference to the thought or process itself rather then the person.  A prerequisite of future tasks may not be quite what you are looking for, but it is a different perspective to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You could also describe someone as being **fixated** on a task. This seems to capture the sense you're looking for almost perfectly. But if you're describing a long-term personality trait rather than describing an immediate behavior, it might not work as well.